# Can anybody give me a description about this?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $x \in A$ and $A \in B$, then why $x \notin B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What about $B=\{ x,A \}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=2$, $A= \{ 2 \}$, $B=\big\{ \{ 2 \} \big\}$. $B$ is a set with an element that is a set. $x$ isn't a set.

Comment: In a constructive sense, $2$ could be a set. Specifically, $2=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. The usual way to deal with this is by having an axiom that says that $A\ne\{A\}$ for all sets $A$.

Comment: But $\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\} \notin \{\{\{\emptyset ,\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I don't get why your comment is relevant to the answer. Whether 2 is a set does not matter in this answer.

Comment: @haruljeon In a lot of widely accepted set theories, claiming that "something on the left side of $\in$ is not a set" is not a viable argument. I can of course be open to the possibility that the person who asked the question is aware of that, and will be able to appropriately give substance to the statement "$\{2\}$ is a set, $2$ is not a set" when the time comes: not that I care too much.

Answer (score 4):

Missouri is a member of the United States.  The United States is a member of the United Nations.  Missouri is not a member of the United Nations.

Comment: Very nice! Let's hope it stays that way.:))+1

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in A$ and $A \in B$, it doesn't imply that $x \in B$.

For example. Let $x=0,  A=\{0\}$ and $B= \{ \{0\}\}$.

$\{0\}$ is an element of $B$ but $0$ is not an element of $B$.